# LINQ-SQL reuse - CompiledQuery.Compile

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have been playing about with LINQ-SQL, trying to get re-usable chunks of expressions that I can hot plug into other queries. So, I started with something like this:

```
Func<TaskFile, double> TimeSpent = (t =>
t.TimeEntries.Sum(te => (te.DateEnded - te.DateStarted).TotalHours));
```

Then, we can use the above in a LINQ query like the below (LINQPad example):

```
TaskFiles.Select(t => new {
    t.TaskId,
    TimeSpent = TimeSpent(t),
})
```

This produces the expected output, *except, a query per row is generated for the plugged expression*. This is visible within LINQPad. Not good.

Anyway, I noticed the `CompiledQuery.Compile` method. Although this takes a `DataContext` as a parameter, I thought I would include ignore it, and try the same `Func`. So I ended up with the following:

```
static Func<UserQuery, TaskFile, double> TimeSpent =
     CompiledQuery.Compile<UserQuery, TaskFile, double>(
        (UserQuery db, TaskFile t) => 
        t.TimeEntries.Sum(te => (te.DateEnded - te.DateStarted).TotalHours));
```

Notice here, that I am not using the `db` parameter. However, now when we use this updated parameter, only **1** SQL query is generated. The Expression is successfully translated to SQL and included within the original query.

So my ultimate question is, what makes `CompiledQuery.Compile` so special? It seems that the `DataContext` parameter isn't needed at all, and at this point i am thinking it is more a convenience parameter to generate full queries.

Would it be considered a good idea to use the `CompiledQuery.Compile` method like this? It seems like a big hack, but it seems like the only viable route for LINQ re-use.

**UPDATE**

Using the first `Func` within a `Where` statment, we see the following exception as below:

```
NotSupportedException: Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL.
```

Like the following:

```
.Where(t => TimeSpent(t) > 2)
```

However, when we use the `Func` generated by `CompiledQuery.Compile`, the query is successfully executed and the correct SQL is generated.

I know this is not the ideal way to re-use `Where` statements, but it shows a little how the Expression Tree is generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exec Summary:

`Expression.Compile` generates a CLR method, wheras `CompiledQuery.Compile` generates a delegate that is a placeholder for SQL.

---

One of the reasons you did not get a correct answer until now is that some things in your sample code are incorrect. And without the database or a generic sample someone else can play with chances are further reduced (I know it's difficult to provide that, but it's usually worth it).

On to the facts:

> ```
> Expression<Func<TaskFile, double>> TimeSpent = (t =>
>     t.TimeEntries.Sum(te => (te.DateEnded - te.DateStarted).TotalHours));
> ```
>
> Then, we can use the above in a LINQ query like the below:
>
> ```
> TaskFiles.Select(t => new {
>     t.TaskId,
>     TimeSpent = TimeSpent(t),
> })
> ```

(Note:  Maybe you used a `Func<>` type for TimeSpent. This yields the same situation as of you're scenario was as outlined in the paragraph below. Make sure to read and understand it though).

No, this won't compile. Expressions can't be invoked (`TimeSpent` is an expression). They need to be compiled into a delegate first. What happens under the hood when you invoke `Expression.Compile()` is that the Expression Tree is compiled down to IL which is injected into a `DynamicMethod`, for which you get a delegate then.

The following would work:

```
var q = TaskFiles.Select(t => new {
    t.TaskId,
    TimeSpent = TimeSpent.Compile().DynamicInvoke()
});
```

> This produces the expected output, except, a query per row is
>   generated for the plugged expression. This is visible within LINQPad.
>   Not good.

Why does that happen? Well, Linq To Sql will need to fetch all `TaskFiles`, dehydrate `TaskFile` instances and then run your selector against it *in memory*. You get a query per TaskFile likely because they contains one or multiple 1:m mappings.

While LTS allows projecting in memory for selects, it does not do so for Wheres (citation needed, this is to the best of my knowledge). When you think about it, this makes perfect sense: It is likely you will transfer a lot more data by filtering the *whole database* in memory, then by transforming a subset of it in memory. (Though it creates query performance issues as you see, something to be aware of when using an ORM).

`CompiledQuery.Compile()` does something different. It compiles the query to SQL and the delegate it returns is only a placeholder Linq to SQL will use internally. You can't "invoke" this method in the CLR, it can only be used as a node in another expression tree.

So why does LTS generate an efficient query with the `CompiledQuery.Compile`'d expression then? Because it knows what this expression node does, because it knows the SQL behind it. In the `Expression.Compile` case, it's just a `InvokeExpression` that invokes the `DynamicMethod` as I explained previously.

Why does it require a DataContext Parameter? Yes, it's more convenient for creating full queries, but it's also because the Expression Tree compiler needs to know the Mapping to use for generating the SQL. Without this parameter, it would be a pain to find this mapping, so it's a very sensible requirement.

Comment: I disagree with the conclusion.  All mapping and expression information available to the CompiledQuery.Compile is available during non-compiled query translation.

Comment: @David: As outlined in my answer his code won't actually compile, you can't use an expression like this in the above code. And the conclusion is still valid: Expression.Compile=CLR, CompiledQuery.Compile und DataContext query = SQL (and until the OP proves otherwise, I proclaim this is the same). The reason he got different SQL is becuase he wasn't invoking an Expression, but a CLR delegate.

Comment: Using the `Expression` directly will not compile. I realise that my first example isn't clear, but I am actually using a `Func`. The first example uses a normal `Func`, which produces a query-per-row. Using the same `Func` that has been through `CompiledQuery.Compile`, we only see one query generated, without using the DataContext in the signature! This works in `Where` and `Select` from my limited testing but i'm sure it will work anywhere. I assume the parser ignores the normal `Func` till a later stage.

Comment: @MiG, alright, that's what I thought. Can you carefully re-read my answer and see if you get why this is the expected behavior? From my point of view this is clear, but don't hesitate to ask and I'll try to explain it differently.

Comment: Yeah, I think I understand it now, although I wish the `CompiledQuery.Compile` behaviour was the default behaviour. I will have to get the reflector out to see the exact science for my own eyes. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised why you've got no answers on this so far. `CompiledQuery.Compile` compiles and caches the query. That is why you see only one query being generated.

Not only this is NOT a hack, this is the *recommended* way!

Check out these MSDN articles for detailed info and example:

[Compiled Queries (LINQ to Entities)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx)
[How to: Store and Reuse Queries (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399335.aspx)

**Update:** (exceeded the limit for comments)
I did some digging in reflector & I do see DataContext being used. In your example, you're simply not using it.

Having said that, the main difference between the two is that the former creates a delegate (for the expression tree) and the latter creates the SQL that gets cached and actually returns a function (sort of). The first two expressions produce the query when you call `Invoke` on them, this is why you see multiple of them.

If your query doesn't change, but only the `DataContext` and `Parameters`, and if you plan to use it repeatedly, `CompiledQuery.Compile` will help. It is expensive to Compile, so for one off queries, there is no benefit.

Comment: I have seen those examples before and neither explain the particular questions I am asking. Why are the `DataContext` parameters not required as per my example? Why are the normal `Func`'s not built into the full expression tree on the first two examaples? What is different between the two? IMO I would expect the first two examples to produce 1 query.

Comment: Ok. This seems to give a bit more insight. But I would have thought that the expression tree would be entirely built before any SQL is generated. Your answer makes sense, in that `Select` seems to ignore the first set of `Func`'s until iteration. Also, This yields even different behaviour using the `Func` in a `Where`. The linq query fails to even run (I will update my original question).

Answer (score 0):

```
TaskFiles.Select(t => new {
  t.TaskId,
  TimeSpent = TimeSpent(t),
})
```

This isn't a LinqToSql query, as there is no DataContext instance.  Most likely you are querying some EntitySet, which does not implement IQueryable.

Please post complete statements, not statement fragments.  (I see invalid comma, no semicolon, no assignment).

Also, Try this:

```
var query = myDataContext.TaskFiles
  .Where(tf => tf.Parent.Key == myParent.Key)
  .Select(t => new {
    t.TaskId,
    TimeSpent = TimeSpent(t)
  });
// where myParent is the source of the EntitySet and Parent is a relational property.
//  and Key is the primary key property of Parent.
```