# How to force LINQ to SQL to evaluate the whole query in the database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a query which is fully translatable to SQL. For unknown reasons LINQ decides the last `Select()` to execute in .NET (not in the database), which causes to run a lot of additional SQL queries (per each item) against database.

Actually, I found a 'strange' way to force the full translation to SQL:

I have a query (this is a really simplified version, which still does not work as expected):

```
MainCategories.Select(e => new
{
    PlacementId = e.CatalogPlacementId, 
    Translation = Translations.Select(t => new
    {
        Name = t.Name,
        // ...
    }).FirstOrDefault()
})
```

It will generates a lot of SQL queries:

```
SELECT [t0].[CatalogPlacementId] AS [PlacementId]
FROM [dbo].[MainCategories] AS [t0]

SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[Name]
FROM [dbo].[Translations] AS [t0]

SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[Name]
FROM [dbo].[Translations] AS [t0]

...
```

However, if I append another `Select()` which just copies all members:

```
.Select(e => new
{
    PlacementId = e.PlacementId, 
    Translation = new
    {
        Name = e.Translation.Name,
        // ...
    }
})
```

It will compile it into a single SQL statement:

```
SELECT [t0].[CatalogPlacementId] AS [PlacementId], (
    SELECT [t2].[Name]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t1].[Name]
        FROM [dbo].[Translations] AS [t1]
        ) AS [t2]
    ) AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[MainCategories] AS [t0]
```

Any clues why? **How to force the LINQ to SQL to generate a single query more generically (without the second copying `Select()`)?**

**NOTE:** I've updated to query to make it really simple.

**PS:** Only, idea I get is to post-process/transform queries with similar patterns (to add the another `Select()`).

Answer (score 6):

When you call `SingleOrDefault` in `MyQuery`, you are executing the query at that point which is loading the results into the client.

SingleOrDefault returns `IEnumerable<T>` which is no longer an `IQueryable<T>`.  You have coerced it at this point which will do all further processing on the client - it can no longer perform SQL composition.

Comment: Why it works, when I append another `Select()`?
The `SingleOrDefault` is nested inside another query.

Comment: Not 100% sure about that one.  SingleOrDefault must evaluate the query to determine if the result set has a single record.  In your first case, ToArray is going to iterate through MainCategories and execute SingleOrDefault for the Translations piece (which is nested so you are going to iterate the query for each category).  How do you know if adding the third layer of SELECT sends a single query?

Comment: See my added note about coercing IQueryable<T> to IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: You can see that is a single query in SQL Profiler, LINQPad, ... `SingleOrDefault` does not return `IEnumerable<T>` (check the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359429.aspx).

Comment: SingleOrDefault does not return IQueryable<T> always.  It returns the value or default(T) of the transformed result in the SELECT statement.  In your query above, IQueryable<T> is coming out of your select since it is a sub-query.  SingleOrDefault is a coercing call.  I don't know why LINQ is combining the 2nd query, however.  They must have special logic in the LINQ-to-SQL provider to handle this case, but I bet the explain plan isn't much better.  Just less trips over the wire.

Comment: `SingleOrDefault` is neither returning `IEnumerable<T>` nor `IQueryable<T>`, check the spec: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359429.aspx

Comment: Correct.  See the first part of my last comment.  Sorry, I misread your other comments and thought you were saying it was.  It returns whatever type is coming out of the SELECT transformation otherwise default(T).  Still coerces the query though.

Comment: If your hypothesis were true, how it can "become fixed" with additional copying `Select()`?

Comment: I do not know what is happening under the hood as far as how L2S parses the expressions.  This is specific to the logic of the LINQ-to-SQL provider.  I'm presuming they treat nested Selects as special cases, but I don't have any hard facts to back that up.  Sorry - beyond my knowledge.

Comment: No problem:) Maybe someone who knows LINQ internals will suggest a better workaround or I stick with my current solution (additional copying `Select()`).

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what is going on, but I find the way you wrote this query pretty 'strange'. I would write it like this, and suspect this will work:

```
        var q = from e in MainCategories
                let t = Translations.Where(t => t.Name == "MainCategory" 
                    && t.RowKey == e.Id 
                    && t.Language.Code == "en-US").SingleOrDefault()
                select new TranslatedEntity<Category>
                           {
                               Entity = e,
                               Translation = new TranslationDef
                                                 {
                                                     Language = t.Language.Code,
                                                     Name = t.Name,
                                                     Xml = t.Xml
                                                 }
                           };
```

I always try to separate the `from` part (selection of the datasources) from the `select` part (projection to your target type. I find it also easier to read/understand, and it generally also works better with most linq providers.

Comment: Yes, but my query is not hand written but rather generated. (I posted just really simplified example that is still not working:)

Answer (score 1):

You can write the query as follows to get the desired result:

```
MainCategories.Select(e => new
{
    PlacementId = e.CatalogPlacementId, 
    TranslationName = Translations.FirstOrDefault().Name,
})
```

As far as i'm aware, it's due to how LINQ projects the query. I think when it see's the nested `Select`, it will not project that into multiple sub-queries, as essentially that would be what would be needed, as IIRC you cannot use multiple return columns from a sub-query in SQL, so LINQ changes this to a query-per-row. `FirstOrDefault` with a column accessor seems to be a direct translation to what would happen in SQL and therefore LINQ-SQL knows it can write a sub-query.

The second `Select` must project the query similar to how I have written it above. It would be hard to confirm without digging into a reflector. Generally, if I need to select many columns, I would use a `let` statement like below:

```
from e in MainCategories
let translation = Translations.FirstOrDefault()
select new
{
    PlacementId = e.CatalogPlacementId, 
    Translation = new {
       translation.Name,
    }
})
```

Comment: The original query is much more complex. It is not hand written but rather generated by several functions. I cannot just rewrite the query. Only what I can do is to append another `Select()` which is what the `let` is actually doing.

Comment: Would you not re-write the offending query as that is producing SQL with bad performance, and any other callers could potentially cause massive bottlenecks in your application? The output is the same, mearly a much better input. There is a subtle difference between mine and your query.

Comment: As I have mentioned the resulting query is not hand written but rather generated by LINQ expression tree transforming functions, only way I found is to append another `Select()` query or post transform the LINQ expression tree.

Comment: How is it generated by the LINQ without yourself having some code as input? surely the input is at fault. In this case, `Select` is causing problems as per my answer.

Comment: The simplified input code looks like this: `MainCategories.Select(mc => new { Entity = mc, Translation = mc.GetTranslation() })`. The transforming functions translates `GetTranslation()` into LINQ expressions just before the query is submitted into LINQ-to-SQL QueryProvider. I am currently using 'additional copying `Select()`' workaround. Maybe in the future the LINQ-to-SQL QueryProvider gets fixed to produce single SQL statement when it can or someone will find a simpler workaround than the another full-copy `Select()`.

Comment: Is `mc.GetTranslation()` is a normal function that returns a single instance of a class e.g. `Translation`?

Comment: Yes, it is a normal function, but in this case is translated into expressions. (Since LINQ-to-SQL QueryProvider cannot transform compiled IL into SQL.) (It does not return Translation, but another another class, here represented by the simplified anonymous object.)

Comment: It is due to the way that LINQ-SQL projects the fields in the `Select`. A normal method call will be delayed until POST-SQL, hence why you see a query per-row. Try re-writing the function using `CompiledQuery.Compile`, you should see one query returned.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But this method is translated into expressions. The simplified result is in the question.

Comment: I know. See a question I raised, hopefully this will clear things a litte. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479552/linq-sql-reuse-compiledquery-compile. The double `Select` method is a little bizzare but it does *kind of* make sense.

Comment: Hmm, the double `Select()` does not make sense for me, I consider it as a hack to force LINQ-to-SQL QueryProvider to make a single SQL query:( I hope the QueryProvider will get fixed/improved in the next version of the .NET Framework:) In the meantime, maybe some will find a simpler hack:)